# Get the list of GitHub issues which does not have a specific label

Tags: github, github-api

In GitHub website, I can get the list of GitHub issues which does not have a specific label like this. (note hyphen)

```
-label:3.0.0
```

How can I do the same on GitHub API? Below does not work.

```
https://api.github.com/search/issues?q=-label:3.0.0
```

Comment: hmm.. it seems to be working for me. When i search for `https://api.github.com/search/issues?q=repo:wso2/product-apim` i find an issue `#1924` with the label `3.0.0`. But when i search `https://api.github.com/search/issues?q=repo:wso2/product-apim+-label:3.0.0` i do not find that issue.

Comment: That's really strange. Now it works. :-o Maybe I was doing something wrong before. And it becomes stranger when you point out the exact repo I was exploring :) Thanks a lot.

Comment: Yeah, that syntax should work fine. You might need to isolate it to a specific repository or organization though...